# Travel between Odessa and Tiraspol

Tags: public-transport, ukraine, moldova, tiraspol

Are there any regular transportation from Odessa, Ukraine to the Moldovian independent republic of Transnistria? To be more exact, to Tiraspol?

Do you need a visa to get there?

Comment: Promotional links are not allowed in questions.  I edited yours out.

Comment: You will need to say how much you are willing to pay. Are you looking for a bus? a flight? What nationality do you have? Otherwise this is not answerable.

Answer (score 7):

There's a direct train from Odessa to Tiraspol, Transnistria, though you might not be let off, as there might not be a way to get a visa upon entry. The train continues to Chisinau, Moldova, from where you *can* backtrack to Transnistria.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually great many options for getting to Tiraspol from Odessa including direct buses.  You can see [schedule (Russian)](http://www.avpmr.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&catid=7%3arasp&id=12%3arasptir) that lists 3 direct buses from Tiraspol to Odessa with the same schedule on the [official Tiraspol's bus station site(Russian)](http://vse.md/tirasgara), with reciprocal schedule from [Odessa](http://www.odessa-guide.com/bus_schedule.shtml) and [same again in Russian](http://odessa-pass.at.ua/index/0-21)

In addition there is a [direct train](http://www.uz.gov.ua/en/passengers/timetables/?from_station=23600%2C23629&to_station=23610&select_time=2&time_from=00&time_to=24&by_route=Search) [#632](http://transport.marshruty.ru/Transports/TransportTimetable.aspx?SheduleID=ec53876b-052b-4065-b5f6-fc01a4dcbbc4&From=71951&To=70395) which runs about 3 hours and stops in Tiraspol.

The question of visa is a bit interesting with Transnistria being such a contested territory but the [Russian Wikivoyage page](https://ru.wikivoyage.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5) provides some of the better information on the visa requirements, which are somewhat weird.